# Google cloud to run Python program as localhost server using Cloud SDK shell

Tags: sdk, cloud, gcloud

Google cloud to run Python program as localhost server using Cloud SDK shell

[image]

Error in google cloud shell:

[image: error in google cloud shell]

ymal file codes

```yaml
runtime:python37
api_version:1
threadsafe:false

handlers;
- url:/
  script:test.py
```

test.py file code

```py
print("hello world")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 0):

App Engine is used to host web apps.

I encourage you to have a look at Google's [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart) for App Engine and deploying a "Hello World!" app.

Your Python `print("hello world")` while valid Python is not a web server and won't work as-is on App Engine.

Google's documentation is comprehensive and should help you get to a running app.

Please don't include images in Stack overflow questions because these have poor accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments from DazWilkin,

1. You are using `dev_appserver.py` which is a development server that simulates Google App Engine (GAE) in Production. Google now discourages using that, especially for the newer runtimes like Python3. Instead Google encourages you to ..*[run your application in your local environment with the development tools that you usually use](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app)*...
2. Another possible way of learning to use GAE is to look at/tinker with the code of an App which runs on GAE. For example, you can use our App, [NoCommandLine](https://nocommandline.com), which has a hello world App in different languages including Python

   a) Follow all the steps documented by Google [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads) to install or update the Google Cloud App Engine SDK. You need to follow all the steps so that all the files are installed/copied and the necessary shortcuts created.

   b) Download and install the NoCommandLine App

   c) Open the App, then go to File > New Application, give your app a name (Application ID), select Python 3 under Runtime and click the 'Create' button.

   d) A new application will be created. Select the App, click the 'run' icon. It will open your default browser and display 'Hello World'.

   e) You can now navigate to the directory for the App and open the different files to see the structure and code and you can play around with the code
3. Note that to deploy your App to production i.e GAE Production, you first need to create a Project with the same name as your App running on local host and you need to provide a credit card (Google will not charge your card but you must provide it)